# Java MongoDB Query

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a structure like this in my database:

```
{
  {
     "document_id" : 35,
     "transport" : ["car", "plane", "train", "boat"]
  },

  {
     "document_id" : 36,
     "transport" : ["car", "bike", "train"]
  }
}
```

How would I do a search query to find a document/record with for example transport 'plane'?

Thanks for any help.

Steven

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from MongoShell

`db.find({transport:"plane"})` would do.

MongoDB will search the entire array to match the query in case the value is an array.

Using Java Driver.

Yous first get the Mongo collection

```
List<Map<String,Object>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();
BasicDBObject dbo = new BasicDBObject();
dbo.append("transport", "plane");
DBCursor cur = collection.find(dbo);
while (cur.hasNext()) {
            list.add(JSONHelper.toJSON(cur.next().toMap()));
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

To search for an array containing an element, you can just check for that element against the array.

So, just using: -

```
db.collection.find({transport:"plane"})
```

would give you what you want.

Here's the implementation in Java: -

```
BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject("document_id", 35)
                             .append("transport", new String[] {"car", "plane"});

BasicDBObject doc2 = new BasicDBObject("document_id", 36)
                             .append("transport", new String[] {"car"});

coll.insert(doc);
coll.insert(doc2);

DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("transport", "plane");
DBCursor cursor = coll.find(query, new BasicDBObject("_id", 0));

while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(cursor.next());
}
```

**Output : -**

```
{ "document_id" : 35 , "transport" : [ "car" , "plane"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Document(collection = "document")
public class Transport {


private ObjectId document_id;

private ArrayList transport;



}


//

   List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("car");
        list.add("plane");
        list.add("train");
        list.add("boat");

Transport transport;

transport.setTransport(list);
```